# Changing a button's border color at onClick

Tags: android, button, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, border

I tried to use:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1sp"
    android:background="#000000"></FrameLayout>
```

but it just ended up in failure, as the constraints just went wonky. I've searched all over, but couldn't find a solution that works, and I'm on the verge of tearing my hair out. My code looks like this:

```
button_msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_red);
button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
          greeting = "赤色です" ;                                                 
          btn_send_msg.callOnClick();                                             
      }});

button_msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_blue);
button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
          greeting = "青色です" ;                                                  
          btn_send_msg.callOnClick();                                              
      }});
```

So if I press red, a border (black, etc) appears only around that button, and vice versa for other buttons. It's just to visually represent which state the program is in now.

**Edit: the complete code is below**

```
package app.real_time_chat;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button  add_room;
private EditText room_name;

private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> list_of_rooms = new ArrayList<>();
private String name;
private DatabaseReference root = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    add_room = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_room);
    room_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.room_name_edittext);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_of_rooms);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    request_user_name();

    add_room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(room_name.getText().toString(),"");
            root.updateChildren(map);

        }
    });

    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()){
                set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());
            }

            list_of_rooms.clear();
            list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int 
i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new 
Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
            intent.putExtra("room_name",( 
(TextView)view).getText().toString() );
            intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void request_user_name() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("名前を入れてください:");

    final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);

    builder.setView(input_field);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
              name = input_field.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
            request_user_name();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}


}
```

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/pale_blue"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/alumis_logo"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-4dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_blue"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:text="青色"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_green"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_red"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.284"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_green"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:text="緑色"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_yellow"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_blue"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.407"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_yellow"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="黄色"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_green"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
 />


<Button
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/msg_input"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/msg_input"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.466"
    android:layout_marginTop="-14dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/msg_input"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="460dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="269dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/msg_input"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="394dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp" />

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_red"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:text="赤色"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_blue"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide ur xml code of button

Comment: Seems like you are getting the border because of the padding. Maybe something is on top of the button(text) and the text width is set to 100% and has a background color (not transparent)?

Comment: Could you post the complete code? I don't see any code above that changes the button's colour.

Comment: Yes, I will post the complete code now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create button_border.xml file inside res/drawable folder

**button_border.xml**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"   >

<solid
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" >
</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#F06292" >
</stroke>

<corners
    android:radius="2dp"   >
</corners>

</shape>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {   
         button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_border));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, so in the main.java, I need to set 4 of those setBackground, 1 for each of the buttons? I'm implementing it now, but I'm getting errors on the "button" and "view" symbols.

Comment: Nvm, I've successfully compiled it, but there is no change. For some reason, the "getDrawable"  has a line across it.

Comment: I have successfully gotten rid of the depreciation by changing it to

                btn_send_msg.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.button_border, null));

but after running, the border still did not appear...